# Why is there a need for $\Delta S$ in the curl definition?

Tags: vector-analysis

> [image]

According to what I read in Sadiku, the curl definition requires this surface delta s to tend to zero for the line integral to approach the curl . But why can't we just take the line integral as curl ? Isn't it a good measure of the tendency of a vector field to rotate? Is removing dependency of the arbitrary curve along which the line integral is taken, the only reason for introducing delta s or is there some other reason?

Comment: @Jack But why does delta s appear as the denominator ? Why not just keep the numerator . I understand from the definition the expression is correct but why this definition precisely?

Comment: The symbol $\Delta$ and $S$ are *together* as a whole. $\Delta S$ means the "area" of $S$.

Comment: @Jack , I understood it . We can choose to keep an arbitrary surface when invoking the definition of curl but when we want to examine lets say a very small portion of the vector field this surface might be too large and so we'll have to shrink it or we can just shrink it to a point and generalize the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L$ in the integral is the boundary of $S$. You want the definition be *independent* of $S$.

Comment: okay , so that is the only reason . Thank you